# Installed games showing as not installed

Tags: steam

Everything was working perfectly until a week ago.

But one day, i started Steam, go to my Library. And saw all of my installed games are showing as not installed. Also when i try to to install them Steam says i don't have any disk space. But i **do**!!

**My OS:** Ubuntu 14.04.2

**What i tried**
Uninstalling, manually removing all the data in `~/.steam` and `~/.local/share/steam` and re-installing

Tried to contact Steam Support, but no response.

Comment: Well, just by description it's acting like the space where it stored games is gone.  Have you had any changes to your drives lately?  Anything else worth mentioning happen a week ago?  I don't know enough about Steam on Linux to be too helpful, but that ought to get the ball rolling for me and others, and I'll poke around on Mint in the meantime.

Comment: No harddrive is fine. I have one drive and everything is installed there.

Comment: If I'm reading [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/227502/where-are-steam-games-installed) right, removing ~/.local/share/steam would have removed everything, nuclear option on steam and its games.  So the question is no longer why aren't the games showing up, it's why won't they install?  And it says no space?  What does df say?

Comment: Yes. I backed up the games. And placed it again after the reinstall. Still no luck. And `df` says i'm only using 22% of my drive. So there is plenty of space.

Comment: Well, I'm not much help then.  But I did find [this bug report](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/3936).  Looks recent. (updated link with better one)  Says something about a kernel update in Ubuntu?

Comment: @Radhil Yes. Updating to -61 kernel fixed it. I guess i will watch that repo for future issues :)

Can you answer the question, so i can give you the bounty?

Comment: Glad I could help.  Apologies for covering the utterly basic, I'm never sure when I've missed a detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this was a bug related to Ubuntu's kernel 3.13.0-59, and was found [documented and discussed on Steam's Github repo](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/3936).  The bug prevented Steam from accessing it's own library folders.

Ubuntu has since updated the kernel again to 3.13.0-61 and this update will resolve the issue.